# modal responsive adapt to screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap modals. I'm trying to show the modal on all screen sizes.

When I use a larger screen, it's look like:

[image]

But then on smaller screens, it's look like this:

[image]

Does anybody know how to adapt the text and button on smaller sizes windows?

EDIT:

Modal in HTML file:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal{{secteur.secteur}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h2 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Achat d'entrées pour le spectacle du <span class="dateModal"></span></h2>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
            <h4>Combien d'entrées désirez-vous acheter dans le secteur {{secteur.secteur}}?</h4>
            {{ form_start(formulaires[secteur.id]) }}
            {{ form_errors(formulaires[secteur.id]) }}
            {{ form_widget(formulaires[secteur.id].quant, {'label': "Quantités"}) }}
         </div>
         <div class="modal-footer">
            {{ form_widget(formulaires[secteur.id].ajouterCont, {'label': "Ajouter et continuer les achats"}) }}
            {{ form_widget(formulaires[secteur.id].ajouterRest, {'label': "Ajouter et passer commande"}) }}
            {{ form_end(formulaires[secteur.id]) }} 
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Annuler</button>
         </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /.modal-content -->
   </div>
   <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

The class of the form inside the modal:

```
<?php

namespace theatreBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class BilletType extends AbstractType {

    private $text;

    public function __construct($text) {
        $this->text = $text;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder
                ->add('dateChoisie', 'hidden')
                ->add('ajouterCont', 'submit', array('attr' => array('class' => 'btn btn-success')))
                ->add('ajouterRest', 'submit', array('attr' => array('class' => 'btn btn-success')))
                ->add('quant', 'choice', array(
                    'choices' => array(
                        '1' => '1',
                        '2' => '2',
                        '3' => '3',
                        '4' => '4',
                        '5' => '5',
                        '6' => '6',
                        '7' => '7',
                        '8' => '8',
                        '9' => '9',
                        '10' => '10',
                        '11' => '11',
                        '12' => '12'
                    ),
                    'preferred_choices' => array('1'),
        ));
    }

    public function getName() {
        return $this->text;
    }

}
```

Comment: could you show your HTML markup for your modal?

Comment: and your css styles also

Comment: I have edit my post, I haven't css file, I use this from bootsrap

Comment: @anubis Since you don't have the CSS it is going to make it harder to help you out. It looks like your main issue is the **font and button-size**. Try overiding the existing styles and change these using **media queries**. You might also need to increase the height of the modal.

Comment: @anubis could you also post the rendered HTML content? (Load the page open the modal, right-click and select "inspect element" then select and copy and paste that HTML markup here also)

Comment: I cannot copy, but here an image: http://puu.sh/iGYy8/cb93e35b4d.png

Answer (score 0):

Just **add** `<div class="clearfix"></div>` between `modal-header` and `modal-body` classes then between `modal-body` and `modal-footer` classes.

**E.g.**

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h2 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">
        Achat d'entrées pour le spectacle du 
        <span class="dateModal"></span>
    </h2>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <h4>Combien d'entrées désirez-vous acheter dans le secteur {{secteur.secteur}}?</h4>
    {{ form_start(formulaires[secteur.id]) }}
    {{ form_errors(formulaires[secteur.id]) }}


    {{ form_widget(formulaires[secteur.id].quant, {'label': "Quantités"}) }}

</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    {{ form_widget(formulaires[secteur.id].ajouterCont, {'label': "Ajouter et continuer les achats"}) }}
    {{ form_widget(formulaires[secteur.id].ajouterRest, {'label': "Ajouter et passer commande"}) }}
    {{ form_end(formulaires[secteur.id]) }} 
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Annuler</button>
</div>
```

`clearfix` class is a default class of **twitter-bootstrap**.

**Update:**

You can also add it inside the bottom of `modal-header`, `modal-body`, and `modal-footer`.

**E.g.**

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h2 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">
        Achat d'entrées pour le spectacle du 
        <span class="dateModal"></span>
    </h2>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <h4>Combien d'entrées désirez-vous acheter dans le secteur {{secteur.secteur}}?</h4>
    {{ form_start(formulaires[secteur.id]) }}
    {{ form_errors(formulaires[secteur.id]) }}


    {{ form_widget(formulaires[secteur.id].quant, {'label': "Quantités"}) }}

    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    {{ form_widget(formulaires[secteur.id].ajouterCont, {'label': "Ajouter et continuer les achats"}) }}
    {{ form_widget(formulaires[secteur.id].ajouterRest, {'label': "Ajouter et passer commande"}) }}
    {{ form_end(formulaires[secteur.id]) }} 
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Annuler</button>
</div>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

which Bootstrap version are you using? 
Using the default files from Bootstrap 3, it seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/b301ckyv/

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

Comment: it all really depends on what the rendered content of the `form_widget`'s are, what classes do they have on them?